# Exporting a list with lookup fields

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, export, import

I'm in a situation where I need to export 2 lists from site Site A to Site B.

The lists I'm exporting have a lookup relation. List X has a lookup to List Y.

List Y gets imported to the new location successfully. But List X does not.

When I try to import List X, no rows are added to the new location because the lookup fields are still pointing to the old GUID of List Y.

I've looked into the manifest.xml file generated and I see in the data xml that foreach row the lookup field has a value like `#82;{Old List Y GUID}`

Is there any way to resolve this during importing of data?

I'm aware of the solution where I save List X as a template, including data, and then open the manifest.xml and replace the GUID in the `List` attribute of the lookup field. But the .stp file is too big to be uploaded to the list template gallery on the new site.

What can I do?

Comment: Could back up and restore be an alternative solution?

Comment: @Submits It could be. But if that is not option, what other options are there?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to tools like "ShareGate" etc. the only solution I know of is the one your describing (replace GUID in manifest). Could you maybe increase the maximum upload size temporarily to be able to upload your .stp?